# What is the most commonly occurring fault with this type of electrically driven gyro?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, avionics, electrical-system, magnetic-compass

I have an examination tomorrow about advanced avionics systems ([EASA module 13](http://part66.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Aircraft-aerodynamics-structures-and-systems-syllabus.pdf)) and we are required to troubleshoot a fault with the compass system. What is the most commonly occurring fault with a gyro compass system and how is it detected or identified?

[image]

Comment: It would help if you stated the fault. In my military a/c maintenance gyros failed for mechanical (things like gyro bearing failures) and electrical reasons (chafed wire, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Some idiot using magnetized a read by flux valve. 
Gears  slipping. Sync knob sticking in.
Leaving it in DG mode.so it drifts

Not correcting for Magnetic Variation changes unless you fly along an isogonal